# Powershell Invoke-Expression with SqlCmd

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

When using `Invoke-Expression` `sqlcmd -i script.sql` it seems to only display the first 2 lines returned.

When I run in Query Analyser the script it returns:

```
(2 rows affected)
Changed database context to 'ShopStore'.
(5 rows affected)
Changed database context to 'ShopStore'.
```

However from PowerShell I only get:

```
(2 rows affected)
Changed database context to 'ShopStore'.
```

YET, the whole thing is being run, I can see this by playing with results. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs on [sqlcmd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx):

> SQL Server Management Studio uses the
>   Microsoft.NET FrameworkSqlClient for
>   execution in regular and SQLCMD mode
>   in Query Editor. When sqlcmd is run
>   from the command line, sqlcmd uses the
>   OLE DB provider. Because different
>   default options may apply, you might
>   see different behavior when you
>   execute the same query in SQL Server
>   Management Studio in SQLCMD Mode and
>   in the sqlcmd utility.

Could this be why you're seeing different results??